# PHP put the textbox value in the url

Tags: php

When I search a word in the `textbox` and click the `cart` button. I want to be redirected to the same search page.  For example when i search the word `phone` it will have a `url` like this `results.php?user_query=phone&search=Search` and when i click the `CART` button it will also have the same `url`. But in this code when you search the `phone` and click the `CART` button the `phone` in the url is gone `results.php?user_query=&search=Search`

```
 <form method="get" action="sample2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input placeholder="Search" name="user_query"class="textbox"type="text"> 
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="searchbutton">
         <input type="submit" name="add_cart1" value="cart" class="searchbutton">
 </form>
```

In this code it's not getting the value of the `user_query` textbox (`$names = $_GET['user_query'];` )

```
if(isset($_GET['add_cart1'])){

global $con;

$ip=getIP();
$pro_id = $_GET['add_cart1'];
$check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";
$run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0)
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Item is already added in the Cart!');
        window.history.back()
        </script>";
    }
    else{
     $insert_pro = "insert into cart(p_id, ip_add) value('$pro_id','$ip')";
     $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pro);
     $names = $_GET['user_query'];
     echo"<script>

     window.open('results.php?user_query=".$names."&search=Search','_self');

     </script>";
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is the extra bracket at the end a typo ? Also, do you have an error in your PHP log ?

Comment: caution! Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Are you sure your query is working, I guess there is an error in this line `$pro_id = $_GET['add_cart1'];` as you are passing this value in the query as `p_id=cart` ?

Comment: your sql might always return 0 rows, you used `$pro_id` in your where statement which `$pro_id = $_GET['add_cart1'];` gets the value of your button which is **cart**

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['search'])){ ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.history.replaceState("", "", "result.php?user_query=<?php echo $_GET['user_query'] ?>&search=Search");
                window.location.reload();
            </script>
<?php
        }else if(isset($_GET['add_cart1'])){
            //do something when cart button is clicked
        }
    ?>
     <form method="get" action="sample2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input placeholder="Search" name="user_query"class="textbox"type="text"> 
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="searchbutton">
            <input type="submit" name="add_cart1" value="cart" class="searchbutton">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```